# How to include fonts @font-face

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I have downloaded a font libertaion_sans that is keep inside a Wordpress theme under a font folder like this `\fonts\liberation_sans`

I saw lots of videos on Youtube and some links on StackOverflow, but I failed to include them correctly.[image]

If I am not wrong we have to define these fonts in style.css before actually using this:

```
font-family
```

Can some one please help me.

Currently,

I am interested in using them →

```
font-family: LiberationSans-Bold;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this => **In your css file**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFontName'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('/fonts/font.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

And use like `font-family: 'YourFontName'` in any css rule.

Cheers!

PD: Create each separatly.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LS-bold'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('/fonts/ls-bold.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LS-Regular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('/fonts/ls-regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

**..etc...**
And if you want to use the bold font, you have to font-family:'LS-bold'.
Understood?

Comment: `'YourFontName';` is something we can define? Right?

Comment: Right. Put you font name in it

Comment: In Fact there are 4 ietms: LiberationSans-Bold, LiberationSans-Regular, LiberationSans-BoldItalic so we have to repeat it for all?

Comment: Yeah, they are all diferents fonts, repeat it... you will have 4 font-familys

Comment: I have done it like this let me know if it is correct → https://www.screencast.com/t/IYv2exjrmyg

Comment: I think you have to separate it for use like LiberationSansBold or LiberationSansRegular in font-family.

Comment: Means? Can you elaborate?